# Cassandra service cannot start on CentOS 6.4, starting process is mysteriously killed

Tags: sql, database, service, cassandra

Cassandra version: 2.2

OS: CentOS 6.4

I just follow the documentation [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/install/installRHEL.html) to run

```
[user@centOS conf]$ sudo yum install dsc22

[user@centOS conf]$ sudo service cassandra start
Starting Cassandra: OK
```

But I check the process status by "ps" and no cassandra process running, since the starting process is mysteriously killed. (I run the same thing on my Mac and all works fine, and on CentOS directly type 'cassandra' in command line also works. @update: I tried "yum install dsc20" and working fine too...)

In '/var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log' is like below, **no error message**, **no warning**. Could anyone please have any idea on this? Thanks a lot.

```
tail: /var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log: file truncated
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/AbstractNativeCell.compareTo (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/composites/AbstractSimpleCellNameType.compareUnsigned (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.selectBoundary (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;II)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.strictnessOfLessThan (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
INFO  23:47:52 Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  23:47:52 Node configuration:[authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_directory=/data/cassandra/commitlog; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[/data/cassandra/data]; disk_failure_policy=stop; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_user_defined_functions=false; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_compression=all; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; native_transport_port=9042; num_tokens=256; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_port=9160; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/data/cassandra/saved_caches; seed_provider=[{class_name=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider, parameters=[{seeds=127.0.0.1}]}]; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=false; storage_port=7000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  23:47:52 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  23:47:52 Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 121MB
INFO  23:47:52 Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 121MB
INFO  23:47:52 Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  23:47:52 Node configuration:[authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_directory=/data/cassandra/commitlog; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[/data/cassandra/data]; disk_failure_policy=stop; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_user_defined_functions=false; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_compression=all; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; native_transport_port=9042; num_tokens=256; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_port=9160; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/data/cassandra/saved_caches; seed_provider=[{class_name=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider, parameters=[{seeds=127.0.0.1}]}]; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=false; storage_port=7000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  23:47:52 Hostname: centos-vm.com
INFO  23:47:52 JVM vendor/version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_45
INFO  23:47:52 Heap size: 509214720/509214720
INFO  23:47:52 Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 636288(621K) committed = 2555904(2496K) max = 50331648(49152K)
INFO  23:47:52 Par Eden Space Heap memory: init = 104071168(101632K) used = 50207568(49030K) committed = 104071168(101632K) max = 104071168(101632K)
INFO  23:47:52 Par Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 12976128(12672K) used = 0(0K) committed = 12976128(12672K) max = 12976128(12672K)
INFO  23:47:52 CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 392167424(382976K) used = 0(0K) committed = 392167424(382976K) max = 392167424(382976K)
INFO  23:47:52 CMS Perm Gen Non-heap memory: init = 21757952(21248K) used = 12843096(12542K) committed = 21757952(21248K) max = 174063616(169984K)
INFO  23:47:52 Classpath: /etc/cassandra/conf:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/airline-0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-core-2.2.0-rc2-SNAPSHOT-20150617-shaded.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/crc32ex-0.1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ecj-4.4.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-16.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/javax.inject.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/joda-time-2.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/logback-core-1.1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-3.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-logback-3.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ohc-core-0.3.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ohc-core-j8-0.3.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config3-3.0.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-base-3.0.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/sigar-1.6.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.1.1.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/stream-2.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/stress.jar::/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a **memory problem**. Since the starting process is mysteriously killed, the fact is it's **killed by kernel**.

I'm running it on virtual machine with 1G memory.

When I run "**ps -ef | grep cassandra**" and then "**dmesg | egrep -i -B100 'cassandra-pid'**", I got

```
Out of memory: Kill process 9450 (java) score 218 or sacrifice child
Killed process 9450, UID 0, (java) total-vm:1155600kB, anon-rss:797292kB, file-rss:100956kB
```

Thus confirmed it's a memory issue. Then I just modified the memory allocation for Cassandra and all worked fine.

in **cassandra-env.sh**

change:

```
half_system_memory_in_mb=`expr $system_memory_in_mb / 2`
quarter_system_memory_in_mb=`expr $half_system_memory_in_mb / 2`
```

to be:

```
half_system_memory_in_mb="300"
quarter_system_memory_in_mb="300"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can seet by typing command netstat -tunlp on the prompt , there you will find process id for the port 7199 . then you have to kill it if you want to stop .

netstat -tunlp tell us port wise process id .

Comment: why port 7199? Cassandra default port is 9042. Also, I think just use "ps -ef | grep cassandra" will grep the process id

Comment: because 7199 is jmx port of cassandra and we can see all process running on port . your command alos will work .